# Map.size returns 0 and Map.values() returns empty iterator even though the map is populated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps

I'm fetching objects from an API and populating a map with them before passing them to a child component as props. The problems is although the when I `console.log(map)` it has the expected object in it - `console.log(map.size)` is `0`. Similarly `map.values()` returns an empty iterator.

This is just confusing for me. The child rendered perfectly when I was only passing one object to it as props - but now that I'm trying to fetch and pass multiple objects I can't seem to get the data structure to work for me.

To be clear, I'm well aware the the `GraphUI` component may well not be processing the map props in the correct way. However, I first want to verify that the data is being passed down properly and so far it doesn't seem to be.

So I guess my question is - what's the best data structure to use to pass the multiple objects I'm fetching down as props that can be easily iterated over?

```
const Graph = ( { geoCodes, dataChoice } ) => {
    const [healthWards, setHealthWards] = useState(null);


    const url = '...';

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = (geoCodes) => {
            var map = new Map();
            geoCodes.forEach(geoCode => axios.get(url.concat(geoCode))
                .then(response => {
                    map.set(response.data.name, response.data);
                 })
                .catch(error => console.error(`Error: ${error}`))
            );
            setHealthWards(map);
        };
        getData(geoCodes);
    }, [geoCodes, healthWards]);

    return (
        <>
        {healthWard !== null ?
            <GraphUI 
                healthWards={healthWards} 
                dataChoice={dataChoice}
            /> 
            : <LoadingSpinner />
        }
        </> 
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't waiting for your promises to resolve and update `map` before calling `setHealthWards(map)`. A good way around this is to use `Promise.all()`, which takes an iterable of promises and returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable are resolved:

```
const geoData = new Map();
Promise.all(geoCodes.map(geoCode => {
    return axios.get(url.concat(geoCode))
        .then(response => geoData.set(response.data.name, response.data))
})).then(() => setHealthWards(geoData);
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! I guess I need to go and do some more reading about async and promises in JS.